# How to hide Firebase configuration in angular compiled bundle

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, gitlab-ci

I'm building an Angular app hosted on Firebase with authentication and Firestore database.
I have my environment.prod.ts that look like this:

```js
export const environment = {
    production: true,
    debug: false,
    firebase: {
        apiKey: "MY_API_KEY",
        authDomain: "MY_AUTH_DOMAIN",
        projectId: "MY_PROJECT_ID",
        storageBucket: "MY_STORAGE_BUCKET",
        messagingSenderId: "MY_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID",
        appId: "MY_APP_ID",
        measurementId: "MY_MEASUREMENT_ID"
    }
};
```

In my gitlab-ic pipeline, I use the sed command to replace the firebase placeholder with real values and then build the app like this:

```yaml
build_app:
    stage: build
    dependencies:
        - install_dependencies
    script:
        - sed -i "s|MY_API_KEY|${FIREBASE_API_KEY}|g" src/environments/environment.prod.ts
        - sed -i "s|MY_AUTH_DOMAIN|${FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN}|g" src/environments/environment.prod.ts
        - sed -i "s|MY_PROJECT_ID|${FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID}|g" src/environments/environment.prod.ts
        - sed -i "s|MY_STORAGE_BUCKET|${FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET}|g" src/environments/environment.prod.ts
        - sed -i "s|MY_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID|${FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID}|g" src/environments/environment.prod.ts
        - sed -i "s|MY_APP_ID|${FIREBASE_APP_ID}|g" src/environments/environment.prod.ts
        - sed -i "s|MY_MEASUREMENT_ID|${FIREBASE_MEASUREMENT_ID}|g" src/environments/environment.prod.ts
        - npm run build --prod
    artifacts:
        paths:
            - dist/
    rules:
        -   if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "main"'
            changes:
                - '**/*'
```

Then, the next stage deploy my app on Firebase and this work just fine.

My problem is that if I open the developer tools in Firefox and read the generated main.xxxxxx.js file, I can clearly find my Firebase configuration as the environment.prod.ts file doesn't seem to be obfuscate:
[Plain text Firebase configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nOs4C.png)

I'm aware that the best way is to modify the security rules on my Firebase project, but I think that code obfuscation should not be neglected as it would make it more difficult for attackers.

How can I prevent the Firebase configuration from being in plain text?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can't truly "secure" this. All you can do is make it a bit more difficult for someone to deal with.  Since all of the data and code is loaded in the client app, someone can easily take all that data and reverse engineer it.  You're better off taking the time to actually implement real security with user auth and rules, and adding Firebase App Check to defend against suspicious behavior. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37482366/is-it-safe-to-expose-firebase-apikey-to-the-public

Comment: Thank you very much @DougStevenson, I'll consider securing my firebase rules.